# Laravel 4 Large data to PDF

Tags: laravel-4, server, pdf-generation

I have  project with Laravel 4.

I am getting large data from server to generate a PDF file.
I have to view the PDF not download.
I have checked the memory limit in PHP.in .On our local server it dose work but on live server I get this Error:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Can you please add more details to the question like the code which you have tried so that it is easier for anyone to answer your question?

Comment: I am almost sure that the issue is in server or in php.in limitation 
not in code as it works at local server. Also for 2000 data it works on live but when it generates PDF for 15000 data I have the following error:

I have project with Laravel 4.

I am getting large data from server to generate a PDF file. I have to view the PDF not download. I have checked the memory limit in PHP.in .On our local server it dose work but on live server I get this Error:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.